# Expecting tx value to be returned by PayPal but getting empty POST request

Tags: php, paypal

I am setting up an e-commerce website using PayPal as a gateway. I have my return URL on my PayPal developer account, and indeed PayPal does redirect me there when I have completed my payment. (I am using a sandbox account.)

However, I am expecting PayPal to include a `tx` value in their request. For the given page, my PHP script simply echoes `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and shows an empty array when I'm redirected there from PayPal.

I have tried sending a dummy POST request using a Chrome extension to the same page and the content is reflected by what PHP returns. I have used the exact same URL as PayPal return URL and in my POST requests.

Any advice?

Comment: You should include relevant code as this would help the responses you get.

Comment: Do you have PDT and Auto-Return enabled in your PayPal account profile?